# executing the round robin algorithm for scheduling of machines in java

Tags: java, algorithm

in the database, I have table that includes `machine_id` and `burst_time` for each machine

```
mach_id      burst_time
1               3
2               2
3               1
4               2
5               4
```

my round robin algorithm code is:

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery("select burst_time from virtual_machine WHERE VM_id <= '"
                                            + size + "'");
                while (rs.next()) {
                                                            list22.add(rs.getString("burst_time"));

            }
            long[] bur = new long[list22.size()];
            long[] rem = new long[list22.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list22.size(); i++) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                                                        formatter1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

 try {
        java.util.Date d1 = formatter1.parse(list22.get(i));
    long btm = d1.getTime();
    rem[i] = bur[i] = btm;
   } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e1.getMessage());
    }
                }

    List<Integer> execOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //for (long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); currTime <=currTime+ et1; currTime += 10 * 1000) {
    do {
        flagClounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (rem[i] > 0) {
                if (rem[i] > qtm) {
                    execOrder.add(i + 1);
                    rem[i] = rem[i] - qtm;
                    flagClounter++;
                    // Thread.sleep(40000);
                } else {
                    execOrder.add(i + 1);
                    rem[i] = 0;
                    flagClounter++;
                }
            }
        }

        //flagClounter++;
    } while (flagClounter > 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < execOrder.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("\nVM " + execOrder.get(i));
    }
```

Here the round robin concept works fine..and it prints the following when time quantum = 2

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 5
```

but what I want is to print the exact `machine_id's` instead of these above integer values that is stored in the array and it gets incremented with the loop..   how can I get the exact machine_id's that is stored in the database to be used in the program and to print it in the same above form after scheduling... can anyone please help me how to put that in the program....

Answer (score 1):

`rem` appears to be an array of the remaining burst times.  If instead it were an array of objects, each representing a machine, you would have both the remaining burst time AND the machine id (and whatever else you wanted) available for printing.

You could alternately create a second array, name (for example) `mid`, such that `mid[i]` is the machine id associated with the machine whose time is being tracked in `rem[i]`.  Now instead of `execOrder.add(i+1)`, you'd do `execOrder.add(mid[i])`.

Comment: yaa.. I got your point.. but how can I put that in the program I'm getting confused,,, if u can explain me with the help of an example..it would be a great help...

Comment: Can you show the code where you filled values in rem?

Comment: @ScottHunter yaa..okay I can retrieve the machine id's and put it in an arraylist. but how can I add the following into the loop.. that's what I'm confused. Because at present in the program just the "i" value is incrementing..but how can I do with this arraylist

Comment: @user2881767 I've updated my code with the codes of filling the rem.. please tell me how can I use the array if I store the mach_id into an array list...

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you I did according to ur suggestion ..its working fine.. but if I change the machine_id's to 101,201..etc.. its showing error.. so I should change the for loop of the same ??

Comment: @sb15: Clearly something needs to change, but having seen neither the code nor the error, couldn't give even a hint as to what.

Comment: @ScottHunter the code is same as the above and I included execOreder.add(mid[i]) but here if I give the machine_id as 1,2,3 its fine..but if I change to 101,201..etc its showing error in the for loop, because the for loop starts with i=0 so is that the problem here??

Comment: @ScottHunter so here how can i change the for loop so that i can iterate over the arrays..please help me in that. i have not changed the above code, just did the modification as u said.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following changes to your code:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> machine = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();    
//Map 'machine' will store each entry as machine_id, burst_time
ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery("select burst_time, machine_id from virtual_machine              WHERE VM_id <= '"+ size + "'");
    while (rs.next()) {
          machine.put(rs.getInt("machine_id"), rs.getInt("burst_time");
    }
```

All your burst times have the machine id's as key. So that you can print corresponding machine id's instead of burst times.